# IntelliJ: Gradle build. Output path is not changing

Tags: gradle, tomcat, intellij-idea

I want to change the path of my outputs but it keeps coming out as the initial path. Why can't the settings be applied?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `project.buildDir = 'any_output_path_that_you_need'` in `build.gradle` to change the build folder.
The IDEA uses the Gradle as single truth of source, and you need to change the Gradle configuration to change these.

Comment: thx but I got "Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

Comment: thx but I got "Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Failed to create parent directory '/webapps' when create directory '/webapps/WEB-INF/classes/java/main'

Comment: @DawnShin `/webapps` looks incorrect to me. Maybe you need to use the `./webapps/xxx` or `webapps` here because the `/webapps` would try to create a folder in your `/`.